# How to get entity query result as Object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-4.3

```
 $contacts = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
                                ->getRepository(Contact::class)
                                ->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                ->select('c')
                                ->where('c.author = :id')
                                ->setParameter('id',$this->getUser()->getId())
                                ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I am super new to symfony and doctrine but i trying to get it.

So i have some result from query build as doctrine as you can you

how i get this result as Json

as long i know how to to loop throughs it

```
foreach($contact as $contact){
  $contact->getId() // or whatever
}
```

beside that i i want get all result as 1 array Objects

I think question label is wrong hope someone will fix it for me because i dont explain it how sorry

**This is contact Entity**

```
class Contact
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25)
     */
    private $Name;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Утасны дугаар оруулна уу")
     */
    private $mobile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, nullable=true)
     */
    private $email;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Утасны дугаар оруулна уу")
     */
    private $mobilesecond;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, nullable=true)
     */
    private $work;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, nullable=true)
     */
    private $position;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\user", inversedBy="contacts")
     */
    private $author;



    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Name;
    }

    public function setName(string $Name): self
    {
        $this->Name = $Name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMobile(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mobile;
    }

    public function setMobile(string $mobile): self
    {
        $this->mobile = $mobile;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMobilesecond(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mobilesecond;
    }

    public function setMobilesecond(string $mobilesecond): self
    {
        $this->mobilesecond = $mobilesecond;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getWork(): ?string
    {
        return $this->work;
    }

    public function setWork(string $work): self
    {
        $this->work = $work;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPosition(): ?string
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function setPosition(string $position): self
    {
        $this->position = $position;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAuthor(): ?user
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function setAuthor(?user $author): self
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

i have test contact data as

[image]

and i think i prefer this kind of object

```
{
 ['51','dfgds','sfg','gfsgfs','s','fg','fgs','1'],
 ['54','dfg','gdf','gd','fgdf','dfgdg','fgdg','1'],
 ['55','wer','','ewe','','','erwrewwer','1'],
}
```

or anything

Comment: maybe you want to show us, how a contact object looks like and what the desired result is ...

Comment: people are quick to downvote, sadly. However, I think you should take a look at the JsonSerializable interface (php standard interface), implement it on your Contact entity and then json_serialize the array of objects.

Comment: i tried serializer but its not compatible because serializer works on object to json but its entity is not object at first place

Comment: sorry, I meant `json_encode`, when you implement the JsonSerializable interface (https://www.php.net/JsonSerializable) on your Contact entity and call `json_encode` on an array of Contact entities, it will call the jsonSerialize method on each entity, so you can decide what is in your result. also, your desired output is not valid json (just saying). (and, entities *are* objects)

Comment: hmm i wonder why its comes [{},{},{}]. I used json_encode

Comment: have you implemented the JsonSerializable interface though? (also with `implements \JsonSerializable` in the class header). if so, how does your jsonSerialize method look?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a controller you can return to the object via => return new JsonResponse ($ objectList)